# Update menu on automatic login with firebase on ionic/angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a slide menu in my app.component. It has a Link to a login page and a logout button. They are toggled with a *ngIf which checks if there is currently a user logged in like this: firebase.auth().currentUser;

This works fine on login. But when I reload the app, the app.component doesnt check if there is still a user logged in and it always shows the login button. Once I hit any button on the menu it refreshes and shows the correct buttons.

Is there any way to trigger the app.component to check for a user and refresh the menu?

Hope my problem is somewhat understandable.

app.component.html

```
<ion-menu-toggle>
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="'/login'" *ngIf="!getUser()">
              <ion-icon slot="start" name="key"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Einloggen</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="'/home'" (click)="logout()" *ngIf="getUser()">
              <ion-icon slot="start" name="log-out"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Ausloggen</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
```

app.component.ts

```
getUser() {
    return firebase.auth().currentUser;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an observer to onAuthchanged event

```
LoggedIn = false;
CheckLoggedIn(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) =>{ 
    if(user) { this.loggedIn = true ; 
    }
    else { this.loggedIn =false; 
    } });
}
```

Use loggedIn variable in template and call checkLoggedIn() from ngOnInit

Comment: it still doesnt work. I've checked the variable and it's set to true as supposed, but the menu only updates once a link on it is clicked...

Comment: Can you create a small example on stackblitz

Comment: I cant believe it.. I created an example on stackblitz and it worked perfectly fine. So I restarted my IDE and now it works there too. Thanks for your help, your solution works! Should have tried this earlier, not the first time i ran into an IDE issue :D